# How to register an event in a usercontrol defined in parents?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have:

A.xaml
A.xaml.cs

MyuserControl.xaml
MyuserControl.xaml.cs

in A xaml I create `<MyuserControl x:Name="MyuserControl"   />`
in MyuserControl `DataGrid`

I need register event `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` and description in A.xaml.cs.

```
public void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){}
```

I need to add the event was in XAML
How do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well in A.xml.cs

You could go like this in the constructor for example:

```
MyUserControl.DataGrid.SelectionChanged += new .....(DataGrid_SelectionChanged);
```

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Alex Hope O'Connor, oh sorry I forgot to say, I need to add the event was in XAML